# How do modals works in react native

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm a newbie using React Native, I'm trying to make modals for my app. I read the documentation but it's not same for my app.
This is my code:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Text, View, Modal, StyleSheet, Button } from 'react-native';



class App extends Component 
{
  constructor(props)
  {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      visibleModal: false
    }
  }


  showModal()
  {
    this.setState({ visibleModal : true })
  }

  closeModal()
  {
    this.setState({ visibleModal : false })
  }

  render(){

    return(


      <View style={styles.container}> 
        <Modal visible={this.state.visibleModal}>
          <View>
            <Text> Hello World in Modal </Text>
            <Button title='Close Modal' onPress={ this.closeModal }/>
          </View>
        </Modal>
        <Button title=' Show Modal ' onPress={ this.showModal }/>
      </View>
    )
  }
}



const styles = StyleSheet.create ({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    textAlign: 'center',
    margin: 100

  }
})
export default App
```

i used snack for this example ( https://snack.expo.io/@yepezaurio/hello-react-navigation-|-react-navigation )

If you are good at using React I want to know two things:
1. What do I need to know or what should I learn to be better at using react?
2. What technologies or libraries are necessary?

Answer (score 0):

The way I see it, your  component in modal has no size. 
One thing I can think is like that

```
  <View style={styles.container}> 
        <Modal visible={this.state.visibleModal}>
          <View style={styles.container>
            <Text> Hello World in Modal </Text>
            <Button title='Close Modal' onPress={ this.closeModal }/>
          </View>
        </Modal>
        <Button title=' Show Modal ' onPress={ this.showModal }/>
 </View>
```

If It is now working, I think other way. Thank you